# Switching between dev and prod environments in Java / Spring Boot apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, development-environment

In my Spring Boot apps, I have just started to use different environment for development and get very confused about a proper switch steps and scenarios.

There are also some files that I could not totally understand as there are several conflicted information on the web about these files.

Could you please clarify me about these issues below?

**1)** As far as I know, we can set the environment from the following setting in application properties. Is that true? And is there any other way for to switch between environments?

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: production
```

**2)** There is also another file called `.env` and I think there is also different versions e.g. `.env-dev`. As far as I know, it is used to define environment variables. But, for example when I run the app from IntelliJ, I am not sure if IntelliJ should read variables from it and use when running the app. How should I use this file?

Based on these 2 issues, you can basically give an example scenario to setup dev and prod environment and switch between them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `--spring.profiles.active=<your-profile>` as a program argument. You can use this as well when launching your app through `java -jar <your.jar> --spring.profiles.active=<your-profile>`. This is also explained in the spring boot documentation.

Comment: I also use Environment variable of Intellij in the run configuration. But could you please explain a little bit more how the other things should be  used based on this scenario? For example, if I activate the environment when running the app, is the the only way? Or what is the usage of `spring: profiles: active: production` ? or `.env` file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can use `spring.profiles.active`, but you probably shouldn't, because you specify this in `application.yml` which should be profile-agnostic. Instead as they pointed out in comments it'd be better to rely on e.g. `--spring.profiles.active=dev` which would tell Spring Boot to use properties from both `application.yml` and `application-dev.yml`.
2. I'd not use this file at all and rely on `application.yml`, because of two main reasons:

- you can run your application from Gradle, Maven, IntelliJ, command line and for all those cases you need to handle environment variables in a different way
- you can run your application on various OSes where environment variables are set up separately

If I'd solve your issue with dev and prod environments I'd create three files:

- application.yml for props shared over all profiles
- application-dev.yml for dev props
- application-prod.yml for prod props

Then I'd switch between profiles by specifying --spring.profiles.active=dev|prod`

P.S. As of your questions in comments:

1. In case you specify a profile with --spring.profiles.active=dev`and there's a property e.g.`server.port`in both`application.yml`and`application-dev.yml`the value from`application-dev.yml` will be used. So you can override properties. It's a standard technique for overriding properties.
2. Well, I don't know how you use the properties from `.env` files. Usually environment variables from OS level are accessed in Java using `System.getProperty(String)`. Moreover, some frameworks' usage implies there's a certain property specified, e.g. Apache Spark usually needs `HADOOP_HOME`. So it might be dangerous to remove those `.env` files.
3. For secrets you can use Vault. The idea is that instead of credentials or other sensitive data you specify a key for them and application uses this key to fetch secrets from vault at runtime. This allows to secure the data even if config files leak.

Comment: Very good explanations, thanks a lot and voted+. In this case, I remove `spring.profiles.active` section and will use 3 properties files with `--spring.profiles.active` argument. At this point could you pls clarify me for these points? >>>

Comment: **1.** Do you have any idea about the overrides between `application.yml` and environment specific `application.yml`? I just thought   concurrent props in 2 files, but maybe I should avoid using any   concurrent props in these files, right?

Comment: **2.** Do you mean that I should also remove all of the `.env` files from my projects? If so, when I need to use an environment variable, should I use them via run command, etc?

Comment: **3.** The last issue is securing passwords and secret data on  `application.yml` and `docker-compose.yml` files. I searched many things but some libraries are not working properly, some of them is not suitable for `docker-compose.yml`. So, without Kubernetes, how can I secure parameters in these files for my Spring Boot apps? Currently I use environment variables and say the clients who use or test the app to set their environment variables via .env file or IntelliJ, but ı think there would be more proper ways :(